# How to get debuginfo package for -rt kernel

Tags: package-management, kernel, realtime

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.14.3-rt4 kernel. I have to use `SystemTap`tool and I must have debug symbols to use it. I follow the instruction in [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap) but there are no debug symbols for my kernel and when I try to build a debug info kernel (according to [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap)) I see this:

```
Unable to find a source package for linux-source-3.14.3-rt4
```

What should I do? Please help me.

`uname -r`

```
Linux Gerdu 3.14.3-rt4 #2 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Sep 7 00:21:53 IRDT 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

`awk '/Package: linux-/' /var/lib/dpkg/status`

gives no output

Comment: Why `linux-source-3.14.3-rt4`? I would say you need `sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` to get the source for your kernel.

Comment: I know. When I use sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r) I see that message.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -a`

Comment: And the output of `awk '/Package: linux-/' /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Can you give more information? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Start the commands above in a terminal and add the output into your question.

Comment: I have `Linux Gerdu 3.14.3-rt4 #2 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Sep 7 00:21:53 IRDT 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux` (Gerdu is my computer's name) when I run `uname -r`. And  I don't see anything when I run `awk '/Package: linux-/' /var/lib/dpkg/status`, I mean command line appears again without output.

Comment: That's not a standard kernel.

Comment: I need to use SystemTap on a rt linux kernel.  What should I do?

Comment: Where did you get the kernel from?

Comment: Here: (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x) and the patch from here: (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/3.14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've compiled your own kernel and there is no matching Ubuntu package. Therefore

```
sudo apt-get source linux-source-$(uname -r)
```

or in your case

```
sudo apt-get source linux-source-3.14.3-rt4
```

fails and gives the output

```
Unable to find a source package for linux-source-3.14.3-rt4
```

Download the kernel again ([kernel](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x), [patches](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/3.14)) and enable debug symbols as described [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/CompilingAKernel.html).